# builtins.TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'img'

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img = cv2.imread('image.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresholded = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

cv2.imwrite("image.png", thresholded)

bbox = cv2.boundingRect(thresholded)

x, y, w, h = bbox

print(bbox)

foreground = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite("foreground.png", foreground)
```

This is my code for getting an image and removing black pixels from it. I tried a solution for the UMAT error I found here on stack but then it says "bad type conversion". Could someone kindly help.

Comment: which line of  code makes problem ?

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables - especialy comprare `grayscale` with `thresholded`

Comment: As per the [doc examples](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html), `cv2.threshold()` returns a tuple. To get the thresholded mat you need to access the first element of that tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Problem makes `thresholded` in `imwrite()`  so I used `print()` to see (and compare manually) `thresholded` with `grayscale` which can be used with `imwrite()` without problems.

`grayscale` is array  but `thresholded` has different construction - it looks like tuple with two elements - some number and array. If I use `thresholded[1]` then I get array which can be used with `imwrite()` but i didn't check what I get in `"image.png"`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

img = cv2.imread('Obrazy/21586784_1642005829205281_8345912444787042013_o.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(grayscale)

thresholded = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
print(thresholded[1]) # <-- [1]

cv2.imwrite("image.png", thresholded[1]) # <-- [1]

bbox = cv2.boundingRect(thresholded[1]) # <-- [1]

x, y, w, h = bbox

print(bbox)

foreground = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]

cv2.imwrite("foreground.png", foreground)
```